# The action 'create' could not be found for WatchedWatchersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, link-to

I've searched high and low for this and the other solutions don't seem to help.
The error:

```
The action 'create' could not be found for WatchedWatchersController
```

I get this after clicking a link made with this code in a view:

```
<%= link_to 'Watchlist', {  :controller => "watched_watchers", 
                                    :action => "create", 
                                    :watcher_id => current_user.id, 
                                    :watched_id => user.id}, 
                                    :method => "post" %>
```

My model for this class is:

```
class Watched_Watcher < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :watched_id, :watcher_id

  validates :watched_id, :watcher_id, presence: true
end
```

And my controller is:

```
class WatchedWatchersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @ww = Watched_Watcher.new
    @ww.watcher_id = params[:watcher_id]
    @ww.watched_id = params[:watched_id]
    @ww.save
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I've set up my routes as a RESTful resource:

```
  resources :watched_watchers
```

And rake routes reveals:

```
POST   /watched_watchers(.:format)          watched_watchers#create
```

So I'm stumped and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Weird! did yu try restarting the server..?

Comment: Rename your model to `WatchedWatcher`(no underscore).

Comment: Have you tried removing your logic from the `create` action & replacing with `Rails.logger.info("testing")`? This will allow you to see if the action is actually being found, but your system just gets caught with errors

Comment: I tried restarting sveral time, no luck. I renamed the model and now I am getting this error: 'Template is missing
Missing template watched_watchers/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/james/Dropbox/GitHubRepo/csi-follower/app/views" * "/Users/...'. It looks as if it is looking for a view but I am trying to create a record and reload the same page @Vimsha . No change with Rails.logger.info("testing") with this new error.

Comment: That worked! Once I fixed the model name I just needed to have a redirect back to the same page. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimsha's comment solved it
"Rename your model to WatchedWatcher(no underscore)". And then once I fixed the model name I just needed to have a redirect back to the same page.